# Django model attribute that updates when database is updated

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pandas, django-models

I am a django beginner trying to set up a django project for data analysis. Data from a certain type of experiment is represented by two models "Dataset" and "GeneEntry", where each Dataset represents one experiment and every GeneEntry is one line from a dataset. Each dataset contains around 20000 entries. A gene with the same name can occur with the same gene symbol in multiple datasets.

```
class Dataset(models.Model):
    dataset_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dataset_name

class GeneEntry(models.Model):
    dataset = models.ForeignKey(Dataset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gene_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Pval = models.FloatField(default=0)
    x = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    y = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.gene_symbol
```

On my django project, users can select one of the datasets and plot x vs. y. The colors of the datapoints should be allocated according to a colorscale on a gene specific ratio r = a/b. b is the number of times this exact gene_symbol appears in the database (e.g. 8 out of 10 experiments have this gene -> a = 8) and a is the number how many of these entries have a Pval < 0.05.

Currently, I am doing this by looping over a list with gene names and calling the following method for all of them:

```
def outlier(self, gene):
    a = GeneEntry.objects.filter(gene_symbol__exact=gene)
    b = len(q.filter(Pval__lt=0.05))/len(q)
    return r
```

The loop is called via df.apply and the ratios written to a column of a pandas dataframe which holds my dataset for plotting.

```
df['ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x: self.outlier(x['gene_symbol']) 
                if x['Pval'] < 0.05 
                else 0.0, axis=1)
```

edit: The dataframe initially looks something like this (before adding the ratio column):

```
   id  dataset_id gene_symbol   x   y           Pval  
0   1           1        AAAA   90  1.041421    0.913037   
1   2           1        AAAB   61  1.038197    0.894884  
2   3           1        ABB    27  0.722224    0.550961  
3   4           1        ABC    3   0.857641    0.534781  
4   5           1        ACC    26  0.223732    0.007097
```

The dataframe is populated via pandas read_sql_query according to which dataset the user selected in the beginning.

I already limited the number of genes to query by coloring only the ones that have Pval < 0.05 in the chosen experiment, but this still leads to hundreds of queries per plot amounting to hundreds of seconds of loading time.

My idea was to use an extra model field that will take the current ratio. This would avoid the mass of queries upon plotting, but make it necessary to update the ratio field in all entries every time new datasets are loaded to the database.

Is this a reasonable way to tackle this problem or are there better ways around? How would I implement this attribute, especially since it would need to be updated upon loading new datasets?

Comment: What is df here?

Comment: df is a pandas dataframe object. I included an example for my data above.